# Mesh model for PR2

Tags: ros, model, pr2, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to get the mesh model for PR2?

Can I find it in some packages or from other sources.

Thanks~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61683/mesh-model-for-pr2/) by [Albert K](https://answers.ros.org/users/1569/albert-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 301 on 2013-04-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sven-cremer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4951/sven-cremer/) on 2013-05-22**:
Were you able to create the mesh model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find collada and STL meshes of different parts of PR2 model [here](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/tree/groovy-devel/pr2_description/meshes). If you need PR2 as one single mesh, you can use one of [these](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_common/tree/groovy-devel/pr2_description/robots) xacro models and convert it to a collada mesh using [urdf to collada tool](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collada_urdf/Tutorials/Exporting%20URDF%20to%20COLLADA). You will loose the joints though and also I am not sure how far it will work out.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0